# Why is the retrieved image from Spring Boot not being displayed in the SwiftUI View?

Tags: ios, swift, spring-boot, swiftui

I'm currently working on an app that retrieves a picture from a Spring Boot Server. It successfully converts the image into a byte stream that is sent to the iOS virtual machine, but when the app tries to convert the byte stream back into the original image I only get an empty Image as the result. I think it is because the iOS virtual machine doesn't succeed in turning the byte stream back into the original image.

Here is the code from ExpandedDetail.swift:

```
class ExpandedDetail:ObservableObject,Identifiable,Codable{
    var file: String
    var thumbnail: String?
    var dateTime: String
    init(file:String,dateTime:String,thumbnail:String?){
        self.file = file
        self.dateTime = dateTime
        self.thumbnail = thumbnail
    }
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
        case file
        case dateTime
        case thumbnail
    }
        required init(from decoder:Decoder) throws{
            let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            file = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .file)
            dateTime = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .dateTime)
            thumbnail = try container.decode(String?.self, forKey: .thumbnail)
        }
        func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
            var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            try container.encode(file, forKey: .file)
            try container.encode(dateTime, forKey: .dateTime)
            try container.encode(thumbnail, forKey: .thumbnail)
        }
}
```

Here is the code from BackpackItemView.swift, which shows an image after there is clicked on a thumbnail:

```
struct BackpackItemView: View {
@Binding var detail: ExpandedDetail
@ObservedObject var viewModel: BackpackItemViewModel
var body: some View {
        VStack{ NavigationLink(destination:ViewDrawingView(recording:viewModel.getResource(detail:detail))){
                    Image(uiImage: UIImage(data:Data(base64Encoded: detail.thumbnail ?? "", options: Data.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters) ?? Data()) ?? UIImage())
                }
}
```

Here is the code from BackpackItemViewModel.swift, which asks the Spring Boot server to retrieve the file and then saves the result to a file in the iOS file service:

```
class BackpackItemViewModel:ObservableObject{
    private let url = URL(string:"http://localhost:8080/backpack")!
    func getResource(detail:ExpandedDetail) -> Recording{
        var request = URLRequest(url:url)
        request.httpMethod = "PUT"
        let detailFile = DetailFile(file: detail.file)
        request.httpBody = try? JSONEncoder().encode(detailFile)
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        var link = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        link=link.appendingPathComponent("\(detail.dateTime).png")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){(data,response,error) in
            if let data = data{
                try? data.write(to:link)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        return Recording(fileURL: link, createdAt: nil)
    }
}
```

Here is the relevant code from the Spring Boot class BackpackController.kt, which retrieves the file from the server and sends it to the iOS phone as a byte stream:

```
data class DetailFile(val file: File)

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/backpack")
class BackpackController @Autowired constructor(var backpackService: IDetailsContainerService<Backpack>, var securityService: SecurityService)
{
    @PutMapping
    fun getFileInput(@RequestBody file: DetailFile):ResponseEntity<Resource>{
        val way = file.file.absolutePath
        val path = Paths.get(way)
        val input = ByteArrayResource(Files.readAllBytes(path))
        return ResponseEntity.ok().contentLength(file.file.length()).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM) .body(input)
    }
}
```

Here is the code from ViewDrawingView.swift, which should display the image, but only displays an empty View:

```
struct ViewDrawingView: View {
    @State var recording: Recording
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Image(uiImage: (UIImage(data: try! Data(contentsOf: recording.fileURL!))) ?? UIImage())
        }
    }
}
```

After some research I found out that the files that are saved on my mobile phone are also corrupted.

[Here is an example of a message saying that the png image on my phone is corrupted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RwAy.png)

Comment: Trying to load a remove image synchronously in `Data(contentsOf:)` in a SwiftUI `View` is unlikely to work. Search here on SO or the internet in general about SwiftUI remote image loading to find a number of different solutions or libraries to help you with your issue.

Comment: Also, don't use `try ?`; it is throwing away any errors. Use `do/try/catch`